# Time series with erroneous data

Tags: time-series

I have time series gravity variation data with inherent uncertainty in the data itself e.g. ($x+\sigma_x$) where $\sigma_x$ represent the error in data. Now I am doing time series modeling (ARIMA) for the same data. Whatever theory I have read, they consider that original data has no error but this is not true in my data. When I do modelling, definitely the error in data itself is going to affect the model parameter. I want to know how to incorporate inherent error $\sigma_x$ in my modeling and check its impact on model.

Comment: Do the errors average out to zero? What can you say about the errors? what is the size of $|\sigma|$ relative to magnitude of $x$?

Comment: No. They do not add up to zero. Those are actually measurement error, not the random one. Also that error is same at all the time which means, that if the error at $X_t$ is $\sigma$ then it will be same for all other data point hence $X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, X_{t-3},\hdots$ and $X_{t+1}, X_{t+2}, X_{t+3},\hdots$. The size of $\sigma$ is approx. 1/5 size of the data.

Comment: Your first step is to estimate $\sigma$. If you have evidence that it is constant over time, just subtract the mean from $x_t$ and fit an arima model. If it's not, the task is not quite so simple.